# Extending Python by compiling C code in Cython

Tags: cython

I'm having trouble compiling a particular source file in C from an R package (fastclime) so that I can use it as a Python module. This is my code to extract the R package online:

```
from __future__ import division
import os
import sys
import glob

if not os.path.exists('fastlp.h'):
    ! wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/fastclime_1.2.4.tar.gz
    ! tar -xzvf fastclime_1.2.4.tar.gz
```

Within the R package (in the [src] folder) is the source file [parametric.c]. I'd like to compile this in Python as a module with numpy inputs. Since I can't immediately test the the functionality of this code, I first tried to compile the [fastlp.c] source file. With fastlp, I can create a toy example to test if I successfully compiled a version of fastlp in Python. Then I can probably extend the steps to compile [parametric.c]

Here is my attempt:

1) First I create the header file since it does not exist

```
 %%file fastclime/src/fastlp.h

 int ratio_test0(double *dy, int *idy,int ndy, double *y, double *ybar, double mu);
 void fastlp(double *obj, double *mat, double *rhs, int *m0 , int *n0, double *opt, int *status, double *lam)
 void solver20(int m,int n,int nz,int *ia, int *ka, double *a,double *b, double *c)
 int ratio_test0(double *dy, int *idy,int ndy,double *y, double *ybar, double mu)
```

2) Next, I write the files for wrapping the C code in Cython:

```
 %%file fastlp.pxd

 cdef extern from "fastclime/src/fastlp.h":
 void fastlp(double *obj, double *mat, double *rhs, int *m0 , int *n0, double *opt, int *status, double *lam)

 %%file fastlp.pyx

 cimport fastlp

 def fastlp(double *obj, double *mat, double *rhs, int *m0 , int *n0, double *opt, int *status, double *lam):
 fastlp.fastlp(*obj, *mat, *rhs, *m0, *n0, *opt, *status, *lam)
```

3) Next I use the distutils build system to compile.

```
 %%file setup.py

 from distutils.core import setup, Extension
 from Cython.Build import cythonize

 ext = Extension("fastlp",
            sources=["fastlp.pyx", "fastclime/src/fastlp.c"])

 setup(name="fastlp",
       ext_modules = cythonize([ext]))
```

4) Finally I compile

```
 ! python setup.py build_ext -i
```

#4 is where things fail big time. Not sure how to resolve it in steps 1-3.

5) If all is successful (which it's not), I should be able to run this code (taken from the vignette)

```
 import fastlp as flp
 import numpy as np

 A=np.array([-1.0,-1,0,1,-2,1]).reshape((3,2))
 b=np.array([-1.0,-2,1])
 c=np.array([-2.0,3])


 flp.fastlp(c,A,b)
```

This should output the vector [2., 1.].

I'm not very experienced with Cython or Python for that matter, but getting this functionality would help out a lot with future projects. Could someone please let me know the proper way of taking a source file in C and getting through the steps in interfacing with numpy to create a Python module?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I'm trying to follow the Numpy+Cython example on this site: https://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/interfacing_with_c/interfacing_with_c.html

I've since updated my code

```
%%cython
# import both numpy and the Cython declarations for numpy
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

# if you want to use the Numpy-C-API from Cython
# (not strictly necessary for this example)
np.import_array()

# cdefine the signature of our c function
cdef extern from "/home/bitnami/STA663-pura-project/fastclime/src/fastlp.h":
    void fastlp(double *obj, double *mat, double *rhs, int *m0 , int *n0, double *opt, int *status, double *lam)

# create the wrapper code, with numpy type annotations
def fastlp_func(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode="c"] obj not None,
            np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] mat not None,
            np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode="c"] rhs not None,
            double lam):
    cdef int m1 = mat.shape[0]
    cdef int m2 = mat.shape[1]
    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode='c'] z = np.zeros(obj.shape[0])
    cdef double [:] zp = z #convert from Python to C object
    cdef int stat = 0
    cdef double lambd = 0
    fastlp(<double*> np.PyArray_DATA(obj),
            <double*> np.PyArray_DATA(mat.T),
            <double*> np.PyArray_DATA(rhs),
            &m1,
            &m2,
            &zp[0],  
            &stat, 
            &lambd  
       )
```

However, I get the following error (which I don't understand at all):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-29981393af41> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic(u'cython', u'', u'# import both numpy and the Cython declarations for numpy\nimport numpy as np\ncimport numpy as np\n\n# if you want to use the Numpy-C-API from Cython\n# (not strictly necessary for this example)\nnp.import_array()\n\n# cdefine the signature of our c function\ncdef extern from "/home/bitnami/STA663-pura-project/fastclime/src/fastlp.h":\n    void fastlp(double *obj, double *mat, double *rhs, int *m0 , int *n0, double *opt, int *status, double *lam)\n    \n# create the wrapper code, with numpy type annotations\ndef fastlp_func(np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode="c"] obj not None,\n                np.ndarray[double, ndim=2, mode="c"] mat not None,\n                np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode="c"] rhs not None,\n                double lam):\n    cdef int m1 = mat.shape[0]\n    cdef int m2 = mat.shape[1]\n    cdef np.ndarray[double, ndim=1, mode=\'c\'] z = np.zeros(obj.shape[0])\n    cdef double [:] zp = z #convert from Python to C object\n    cdef int stat = 0\n    cdef double lambd = 0\n    fastlp(<double*> np.PyArray_DATA(obj),\n                <double*> np.PyArray_DATA(mat.T),\n                <double*> np.PyArray_DATA(rhs),\n                &m1,\n                &m2,\n                &zp[0],  \n                &stat, \n                &lambd  \n           )')

/home/bitnami/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2160             magic_arg_s = self.var_expand(line, stack_depth)
   2161             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2162                 result = fn(magic_arg_s, cell)
   2163             return result
   2164 

/home/bitnami/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/cythonmagic.pyc in cython(self, line, cell)

/home/bitnami/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/home/bitnami/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/cythonmagic.pyc in cython(self, line, cell)
    269             self._code_cache[key] = module_name
    270 
--> 271         module = imp.load_dynamic(module_name, module_path)
    272         self._import_all(module)
    273 

ImportError: /home/bitnami/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_16feaf686ed172960f59fa6333ae74b5.so: undefined symbol: fastlp
```

Comment: You really need to know what arguments `fastlp` takes - are `obj` and `mat` pointers to arrays, or just pointers to a single `double`. If they're pointers to arrays, how do you know what size the array is? Which arguments are the inputs and outputs, and how much space do you need to allocate for the outputs? Without that information it's going to be pretty much impossible to wrap, and it's especially optimistic to think you can directly call a function that takes 8 arguments in C with three numpy arrays and expect it to make sense.

Comment: The other think you might think about is using [r2py](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.5/html/index.html) (or some other similar alternative) which will let you call the R functions from Python and avoid all this.

Comment: can you post the error log?

Comment: btw, base on https://github.com/cran/fastclime/blob/master/src/fastlp.c `fastlp.c` depends on other files in the folder, you know you have to also compile those right?

Comment: @DavidW yes, I've looked carefully at the R wrapper for the C file and tried to replicate the argument inputs exactly. I can use r2py, but the function I'm interested in is not implemented with an R wrapper.

Comment: @colinfang I've kept track of the files that go into fastlp.c and they are included in my fastlp.h file.

Comment: I've run `gcc -c -fPIC fastlp.c -o test.o` on the command line and it seemed to run without errors

Comment: Your current problem is that it can't find the implementation of your fastlp function. If uou have a compiled library that contains it (.so file) you can write "%%cython -lc_lib" (dash l name_of library) and it should work. If not them I'm happy to show you how to build them together.

Comment: @DavidW, you're right I don't have a .so file containing fastlp. That would be great if you could direct me in building this. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I think you need to build the module outside of ipython (i.e. not using "%%cython". Have a look at http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html "compiling with distuitls" section. Basically you need to specify fastlp.c as a source file, either in the setup.py file, or as a comment header in your pyd file: "# distutils: sources = helper.c, another_helper.c"

Comment: It looks slightly fiddly but all you really need to do is copy their basic example, change a few filenames, and add fastlp.c as a source file! Good luck!

Comment: @DavidW Thanks, but don't I need a pyx file first? How can I create that with the current structure of my code (i.e. replacing %%cython with %%file "_fastlp.pyx"). I should also add that I'm using an iPython Notebook, if that makes a difference

Comment: I'm not familiar with ipython notebook. I'd open a text editor and copy all your cython code to fastlp.pyx. compile it (and fastlp.c) with "setup,py" as described in the link, and once that's done you can import it like any other module in ipython notebook with "import fastlp"

Comment: @DavidW - I've modified my approach - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337303/extending-python-numpy-with-c-code-questions-on-construction-syntax